# Reverse engineering a byte array of msil code

Tags: .net, reverse-engineering, cil

Is there a way to take a chuck of msil code saved as a byte stream and reverse engineer it to some higher level code (e.g. C#)?

Edit: MSIL instructions that are not a whole assembly

Thanks,

Jon

Comment: Do you mean just a bunch of `msil` instructions that are not part of an assembly?

Comment: Use Reflector to disassemble Reflector, and see how it does it.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't take **"a piece of CIL code"** to decompile it into high level language. High level language aside you can't even properly decompile it. Because, CIL does not mean only bunch of instruction, some instructions have metatokens as operand. Metatokens are simply integer references for some objects (types, methods, strings etc.). Those information are stored in the assembly. Even if we ignore that information, there is another problem: exception handling. There is no "try" and "catch" instructions (but there is endfinally etc.). To determine try-catch/finally blocks you again need assembly. Because, those informations are stored as offset-length pair (blocks boundaries are stored) in assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Reflector does just that... so yes, it is possible, assuming that you do have the correct context (to resolve type tokens etc.).

However, just as with Reflector, the reverse engineered code may be completely different than the original code, but it will have the same semantics (if there's no bug in the code generator).

Comment: Reflector works on _assemblies_. I am not sure this is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: The question was if "there is a way" - my answer is that yes, if you have the additional information required to make something meaningful from all the data in the MSIL stream (opcodes are no problem, but type and method tokens etc. are a problem).

Comment: Oded, True. It is not an assmebly, and reflector does not know how to handle it.

Comment: Lucero, where can I find that required information, and once I have it how can it be integrated with the MSIL code to become a meanningful high level language? (if I understood you correctly it is possible)

Comment: Can you make an intermediate assembly out of the bytecode stream?

Comment: Jon, give us some more information about where you get that MSIL from. Without metadata information, the MSIL stream is pretty useless, because it cannot be bound to types, fields, methods, or even constant strings loaded onto the stack. So the primary question is, do you have this metadata as well? See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404456.aspx for some info on that.

Comment: Sorry merlyn, I dont know what you mean. Can you please supply more information?

Comment: Lucero, that byte stream represents a dynamic loadable method. In order to load elements dynamicly (using reflection) their metadata are not neccesrly attached, correct?

Comment: Can you give more specific details on the "dynamic loadable method" thing? What are they, if not in an assembly? Where do they come from? In order to use anything you need the metadata, reflection is about nothing but metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the .NET Reflector.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Answer (score 0):

Mono.Cecil offers some analysis functionality:
http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil
Not sure if it can analyze pure IL code.

Comment: From the site: "In simple English, with Cecil, you can load existing managed assemblies". So, an assembly is required.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it this will work, but [ILDASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx) sounds about right:

> The MSIL Disassembler is a companion tool to the MSIL Assembler (Ilasm.exe). Ildasm.exe takes a portable executable (PE) file that contains Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) code and creates a text file suitable as input to Ilasm.exe.

Note the requirement for the file to be a PE file, so for anything practical this would still essentially be a managed assembly.

---

Since these instructions are low level, they will not necessarily correspond directly to high level code - even reflector will not give you the exact original code.

You may need to write your own tool in order to achieve this, as an assembly will contain some potentially required information (referenced assemblies, for instance).

Comment: That will how ever only give me the MSIL commands not a high level syntax, correct?

Comment: @Robert Harvey - I don't believe it does. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable

Comment: @Oded: Well, OK. But if the PE has IL in it, that essentially makes it a managed assembly.

Comment: @Robert Harvey - For anything practical, yes.

Answer (score 0):

for people that are yet looking for an answer to this question,
i have found this, maybe it help in some way;
1-im not related with the author of this tool in anyway;
2-it is able to get a textual version of msil from the raw bytecode, not to csharp, bc for that i think its alot more job to do :S:S

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14058/Parsing-the-IL-of-a-Method-Body

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33814502)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).